# Versioning of ViewModels

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0, mvvm

I have a View and a ViewModel. ViewModel not only takes care of View related presentation but also initiates business logic(workflow in our case). My software can talk to different versions of the firmware of the device.

**Use Case 1: View Layout goes through Modification** 
It may be required to display slightly different view when connecting to a different version, in that case, I create a new view and hook it up with a new view model.

> This works well.

**Use Case 2: View Remains Same but Underlying Logic Changes** To understand this, let's say when software connects to a Firmware version(1.0.0) it is supposed to show a view with a checkbox and a Textbox and the Textbox need to be enabled only when the checkbox is checked. Now if Software connects to a different version of firmware(1.2.0) it is supposed to show the same view but now Textbox is not supposed to be enabled/disabled based on the checkbox check.

My questions are,

1. Do I need to create a new View Model?
2. Should I create a flag of some sort in the database(1.2.0) and use the same view model, so the logic in the view model first check whether the flag is present or not then it can decide to enable/disable controls.

Comment: The firmware version, in this case, is part of your business logic. I think you have to create a property responsible to say if the textbox must be enabled/disabled, and then switch it when the checkbox is checked AND the version is different of (or less than) '1.2.0'. Good point. +1

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza I don't want to switch logic based on hard coding because who knows what they ask in version 1.3.0. So you think it may be fine to have a data-driven switch case where information is coming from a new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably going to come down to how different versions 1, 1.2 and the theoretical 1.3 are going to function and/or look.  If it really is as simple as "version 1.2 should not disable the textbox based on the state of the checkbox", then a simple property in the ViewModel to indicate the version of the firmware, plus some simple logic in the view (`if ( Model.Version >= 1.2 ) {...}`) is probably the way to go.

However, if it's more complex than that (and not even that much more complex), I suspect you'll be better off creating custom ViewModels and Views for each firmware version. Otherwise you're going to get into a real tangle as the versions increase and the custom logic increases.  You'll end up with

```
if ((Model.Version >= 1.2 && Model.Version <= 1.3) || Model.Locale == EnglishSpeaking) 
{
    ...
} 
else if ( Model.Version > 1.3 && Model.Locale == EnglishSpeaking ) 
{ 
    ... 
} 
else if ....
```

And that will quickly spiral out of control.  If that happens, you'd better hope that you've got some very concrete acceptance tests around all the required functionality in all the required version scenarios, otherwise no one is going to want to modify that code for fear of inadvertently busting up that logic.